# Can you help me? I am not sure what it means

Tags: word-usage

I am currently reading an IPA(In-principle Approval) for my work permit
but I can not fully understand the following:

AGENCY FEE TO BE PAID TO S'PORE EA(Singapore employment agency)
(EXCLUDE FEES FOR OVERSEAS EXPENCE)

It is from employment details part.
I am not sure what they mean by "overseas expence"

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: This is not really a language question. _Overseas expenses_  are sums of money that have to be paid overseas, but you will have to ask the organisation  issuing your work permit to find out exactly what expenses they are referring to.

Comment: Visit **Travel.SE** ["work permit" fee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22work+permit%22+fee)

Comment: They don't mean **expence**; that's a typo. They mean **expense**. They also likely mean for it to be plural, rather than singular. In short, they mean to say *overseas* ***expenses***. As for [*overseas*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overseas#h2), it just means "situated, originating in, or relating to lands beyond the sea ."

Answer (score -1):

I believe it means that all other expenses relating to your overseas employment (Airfare? Housing Allowance?) is not yet included in that "agency fee". In other words, that amount is the service fee of your agency alone.